# Python array iteration not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x

Using the debug console, I've arrived at the "result" i want. I achieved it using:

`response.hits.hits[0]._source`

So i took it one step further and decided to create a loop:

```
projection = []
for hit in response.hits:
    for subHit in hit.hits:
        projection.append(subHit._source)
```

but now i'm getting a exeception stating that `subHit` does not have `hits` property... and I'm confused...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for hit in response.hits.hits`

Comment: The second hits isn't a property, but it is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `response.hits` is not an array but `response.hits.hits` is an array. So you must be just doing like,

```
for hit in response.hits.hits:
    projection.append(hit._source)
```